# How to pull a symbol from a variable in python?

Tags: python, list, variables

I want the code to select a random symbol from the array and then execute an expression with it.

Here is my code:

```
import random

num1=random.randint(0,10)
print(num1)
num2=random.randint(0,10)
print(num2)
symbol=['+', '-', '*']
symboltype=random.choice(symbol)

answerright=num1,symboltype, num2
print(answerright)
```

Comment: and your problem is?

Comment: So, you want the script to do the math as well?

Comment: `{"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, ...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
import random

symbols = {'+': operator.add,
           '-': operator.sub,
           '*': operator.mul}

num1 = random.randint(0,10)
num2 = random.randint(0,10)

op_str = random.choice(symbols.keys())
op = symbols[op_str]
print('%d %s %d = %d' % (num1, op_str, num2, op(num1, num2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using dictionary. But I've used `if` loop as shown below.

```
import random

num1=random.randint(0,10)
print(num1)
num2=random.randint(0,10)
print(num2)
symbol=['+', '-', '*']
symboltype=random.choice(symbol)

if symboltype == '+':
    answerright=num1 + num2
    print answerright
elif symboltype == "-":
    answerright=num1 - num2
    print answerright
elif symboltype == "*":
    answerright = num1 * num2
    print answerright
```